# Multiline regex not matching

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to get a multi-line regex working with .NET but not having much luck. I believe I'm right in thinking that this will match multiple lines, but the third match is always omitted. I need to capture the recipient and reason fields. I know I could do this with a loop and two regexes but I'd prefer a more succinct solution.

The regex I'm using is:

```
(.*?)Destination: mobile (\(SMS\))?(\d{10,})(?:.*?)Reason: (.*)
```

It should match against this text:

```
NON-DELIVERY NOTE

The following message was not delivered:

Addressed to: 01234567890@sms.local
Destination: mobile (SMS)01234567890
Reference number: 155618127W

Reason: Rejected by network operator
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67798/multiline-c-sharp-regex-to-match-after-a-blank-line

Comment: Its always best when posting a regex question to not just post the regex but to explain what it is that it is meant to do. If the problem is that your regex is wrong we'll never known because we don't have your intent to compare it to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need to use [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) instead of `RegexOptions.Multiline`.